# Hibernate - User and his Report list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity named `User`. I decided that every user has its `Report (also entity) list. Then I created something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    ...
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Report> reportList;
```

Now the `Report` object looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class Report implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private User reporter;
```

Is it right approach? Every user can have many reports, but every report can belong to only one user.

I thought about changing `@ElementCollection` to `@ManyToOne`, but I think I prefer operating on a list.

The main problem is, how to make relation(connection) between user and their reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the right approach. ElementCollection is for a collection of simple types (String dates, etc.) or embeddable types. For a collection of entities, you need a `OneToMany` association (which is quite normal, given that you have a ManyToOne in the other direction):

- one user has many reports
- many reports are reported by one user

.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "reporter")
private List<Report> reportList;
```

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections) covers this in detail.